# Overriding mybatis typehandler

Tags: mybatis, spring-mybatis, mybatis-mapper

Im using latest spring boot with spring mybatis which uses mybatis 3.5.9

I have a pojo with a LocalDateTime and the db has a timestamp.. So I would expect mybatis to convert it.. But since, 3.4.1 there was a change to the mybatis LocalDateTimeTypeHandler that causes a unable to conver to TIMESTAMPZ error..

So I grabbed the previous mybatis LocalDateTimeTypeHandler that works with LocalDateTime and added it to my project.. But, not matter what I do I cannot get mybatis to use the type handler..

I currently have for the type handler.

```
package my.mapper.typehandlers;

import java.sql.CallableStatement;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

import org.apache.ibatis.type.BaseTypeHandler;
import org.apache.ibatis.type.JdbcType;
import org.apache.ibatis.type.MappedJdbcTypes;
import org.apache.ibatis.type.MappedTypes;

@MappedJdbcTypes(value=JdbcType.TIMESTAMP)
@MappedTypes(value = LocalDateTime.class)
public class LocalDateTimeTypeHandler extends BaseTypeHandler<LocalDateTime>{

    @Override
      public void setNonNullParameter(PreparedStatement ps, int i, LocalDateTime parameter, JdbcType jdbcType)
              throws SQLException {
        ps.setTimestamp(i, Timestamp.valueOf(parameter));
      }

      @Override
      public LocalDateTime getNullableResult(ResultSet rs, String columnName) throws SQLException {
        Timestamp timestamp = rs.getTimestamp(columnName);
        return getLocalDateTime(timestamp);
      }

      @Override
      public LocalDateTime getNullableResult(ResultSet rs, int columnIndex) throws SQLException {
        Timestamp timestamp = rs.getTimestamp(columnIndex);
        return getLocalDateTime(timestamp);
      }

      @Override
      public LocalDateTime getNullableResult(CallableStatement cs, int columnIndex) throws SQLException {
        Timestamp timestamp = cs.getTimestamp(columnIndex);
        return getLocalDateTime(timestamp);
      }

      private static LocalDateTime getLocalDateTime(Timestamp timestamp) {
        if (timestamp != null) {
          return timestamp.toLocalDateTime();
        }
        return null;
      }

}
```

and the Results

```
@Results(id = "statusResult", value = {
            @Result(property = "id", column = "id", id = true),
            @Result(property = "patientId", column = "patient_id"),
            @Result(property = "enqueueDone", column = "enqueue_done"),
            @Result(property = "enqueuedTime", column = "enqueued_time")
    })
```

I've tried explicitly setting the typeHandler in the @Result for enqueued_time but the framework still ignores it.

Update: I added
mybatis.type-handlers-package=my.mapper.typehandlers to application.properties. I can hit my break point and it looks all good.. but then mybatis looks like it just call the other LocalDateTimeTypeHandler anyway and I get the TIMEZONEZ error

How can i get mybatis to ignore the mybatis LocalDateTimeTypeHandler?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

ok, so it's been a long hot day.. So I got this to work..

All I needed to do was set the typeHandler=my.mapper.typehandlers.LocalDateTimeTypeHandler.class in the @Result

```
@Results(id = "statusResult", value = {
            @Result(property = "id", column = "id", id = true),
            @Result(property = "patientId", column = "patient_id"),
            @Result(property = "enqueueDone", column = "enqueue_done"),
            @Result(property = "enqueuedTime", column = "enqueued_time" ,typeHandler=my.mapper.typehandlers.LocalDateTimeTypeHandler.class)
    })
```

and include mybatis.type-handlers-package=my.mapper.typehandlers  in the properties file..

I removed

```
@MappedJdbcTypes(value=JdbcType.TIMESTAMP)
@MappedTypes(value = LocalDateTime.class)
```

from my LocalDateTimeTypeHandler class since they were not needed..

All works now.